# Where is org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin 2.0?

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I am currently using the [JAXB-2 Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/) developed by Codehaus (`jaxb2-maven-plugin`) to generate Java classes from an XSD.

The site mentions that the plugin is in version 2.0 (Last Published: 2015-02-09). However, I can not find this plugin on any Maven repo :

- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/jaxb2-maven-plugin is still in version 1.6
- http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.codehaus.mojo%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jaxb2-maven-plugin%22 is also in version 1.6

Where can I find it ?

Also, I tried using the previous version (1.6) but it seems that the configuration of the goal [`xjc`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html) radically changed because the properties described in the documentation for version 2.0 do not exist in version 1.6.

This leads to a second question: where can I find the documentation for version 1.6 ?

Comment: I suggest you [maven-jaxb2-plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/Maven+JAXB2+Plugin) ... works better than `jaxb2-maven-plugin`

Comment: @Xstian This is the correct link: https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin

Comment: @lexicore of course you are right :) .. you are the author of `maven-jaxb2-plugin` :) sorry for the wrong link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm waiting too. But It seem they has some problems with 2.0.

Lennart Jörelid, a project contributor said:

> While the 2.0 version exists in the version control system, it is not
>   publicly released. I am awaiting some feedback from the community in
>   regards to the eclipse m2e integration and - based on feedback - will
>   likely release a 2.1 instead of the 2.0 version for public
>   consumption.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAXB-97?focusedCommentId=364606&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-364606